# Reducing Godel number to a manageable size

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

I have a set of $n$ attributes $A$, i.e. {$A_1, A_2, .. , A_n$}. Each attribute has $m : m > 0$ possible values, which we can call $V_{a,m}$.

I also have a population of objects, which are uniquely identified by the values of the attributes they possess. Each object will have 0 or more attributes; each attribute they possess will have exactly one of the possible values. The attributes fully description the population of objects, and there is a maximum of one object that has any combination of attributes.

Thus I can identify any object uniquely using the set of values that apply to it. e.g. if object $O_x$ has only attributes $A_1$ and $A_2$ with values $V_{1,20}$ and $V_{2,5}$, I can say that $${V_{1,20},V_{2,5} \to O_x }$$

I'm trying to reduce the map of attributes to a single number - think of this as a [Godel Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering#G.C3.B6del.27s_encoding). My current approach is to leverage Godel's prime factor encoding, so that

$$V_{1,20},V_{2,5} \to 2^{20} * 3^5 \to 254803968$$

or more generally, $V_{a,m} \to (p_a)^m$ where $p_a$ is the $a$th prime number. This guarantees uniqueness but the new number quickly becomes too large.

---

**Question:**
Is there any way to reduce the new number to a manageable size, e.g. modulo some large prime? My mind connects back to the Chinese remainder theorem but I'm not able to piece together the pieces.

For reference, I am working with $n < 20$ and $m < 200$.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have to use a Godel encoding? Just use a base $(m+1)$ encoding, where $A_1$ is the least significant digit, $A_2$ is the next, and so on, and a $0$ digit means the attribute is absent, while a digit from $1$ to $m$ indicates that that attribute is present and has one of the $m$ possible values. This allows you to have arbitrary finite length of the attribute list without any collision. To decode use integer division by $(m+1)$ with remainder.

Comment: Godel encoding was only needed in encoding arbitrary sequences of natural numbers (in your cases each term is bounded by $m$) and in such a way that there are formulae over PA that can capture decoding, which is non-trivial and does involve the chinese remainder theorem as you vaguely recall. But it is useless for practical encoding. Even if your attribute values are unbounded, it is better to use something else like universal encoding.

Comment: Good idea and valid point, but the number is still very large i.e. a value in $A_{20}$ will be greater than $200^{20}$.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst and necessarily so. After all, you have about $200^{20}$ possible different objects.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: If your attributes are completely arbitrary, you're going to need that many possible encodings anyway! Don't forget that instead of using base $(m+1)$ you could use base $256^k$ for some large enough $k$ and then each digit will be a whole number of bytes, making it easy to encode and decode efficiently. For the general case of unbounded attribute values, you can use universal coding followed by run-length encoding, but it is tricky to decode efficiently.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: He might be worried about efficiency, so my comment should address that. CS application motivated problems often have all these issues to worry about. =)